# mdframed: splittopskip ignored for center environment

Tags: page-breaking, mdframed

I have a lot of example environments using `mdframed` in my document that break across pages. In these enviroments, I have some tables of results that I currently place in a `center` environment. Unfortunately though, when these tables appear directly after a page-break, the skip set in `skiptopskip` is ignored.

I'm looking for a general solution to this problem, or perhaps even an alternative to the `center` environment that looks the same, but does not encounter this problem.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm, paperheight=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[splittopskip=20pt,backgroundcolor=black!5]
\blindtext

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
A & 1 \\
B & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image: mdframed problem with page breaks and center]

Note that the second page respects the `skiptopsep` but the third page does not.

Comment: Use tcolorbox instead of mdframed. Much more reliable.

Comment: Unfortunately I have made a custom environment with mdframed used in hundreds of examples. I would prefer a solution for mdframed if at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues, neither of which is related to `center`. One can verify this by commenting out the `center` environment...the `tabular` moves to the left, but vertical space is unchanged.

So, what are the issues?

1. The tabular is vertically center-aligned. Try instead `\begin{tabular}[t]...`. That restores top alignment, but with that alone, the space then becomes excessive:

[image]

2. The excessive spacing issue appears to be related to the spacing above `\toprule`.  Here is what you get if do this `X\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}\toprule...\end{tabular}`.  The rule is aligned with the baseline, rather than the top of the letter-space, thus creating extra vertical space.

[image]

My fix is to use `stackengine` to tell it how to place the complete `tabular` relative to the baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm, paperheight=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[splittopskip=20pt,backgroundcolor=black!5]
\blindtext

\begin{center}
\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
\toprule
A & 1 \\
B & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{center}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

In an effort to make it easier for the OP to back-modify an existing document, I wrapped the above approach into a new environment, `qtabular`.  Thus, to fix instances of the problem, the environment merely needs to be changed from `tabular` to `qtabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm, paperheight=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{environ,stackengine}
\NewEnviron{qtabular}[1]{%
  \def\tmp{\begin{tabular}[t]{#1}}%
  \belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{\expandafter\tmp\BODY\end{tabular}}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[splittopskip=20pt,backgroundcolor=black!5]
\blindtext

\begin{center}
\begin{qtabular}{ll}
\toprule
A & 1 \\
B & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{qtabular}
\end{center}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works well, thanks! But any suggestion on how I might implement something in the document head that would not require the explicit `\belowbaseline` command before each tabular? (There are hundreds in the document.)

Comment: @badroit No quick fix jumps to mind.  Remember, you are going to have to add the `[t]` qualifier to all affected `tabular`s anyway...so I don't think you can avoid some level of individual editing.

Comment: @badroit  You could change affected `tabular`s into `qtabular`s with this preamble code: `\usepackage{environ,stackengine}
\NewEnviron{qtabular}[1]{%
  \def\tmp{\begin{tabular}[t]{#1}}%
  \belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{\expandafter\tmp\BODY\end{tabular}}%
}`.  Invocation is the same, except `tabular` becomes `qtabular`.

Comment: @badroit I have provided the above code in an **ADDENDUM** to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Imho, whatever environment you have defined with mdframed you can create it with tcolorbox too - minus the problems you have with mdframed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm, paperheight=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mdframed}{enhanced,breakable,sharp corners,colback=black!5,topsep at break=20pt,boxrule=0.4pt} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
abc\\abc\\\blindtext

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
\toprule
A & 1 \\
B & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]